# cannot connect to mysql on AWS through ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to break down the [task](https://superuser.com/questions/691462/how-to-connect-local-apps-i-e-rubymine-prosequel-to-remote-server-using-aws) of doing AWS debugging on rubymine into smaller chunks. I would like to connect to the mysql server running on AWS. So I did the following:

**first:** Establish an ssh tunnel to forward all localhost requests to port 3307 to the port 3306 on AWS:

```
ssh -l ubuntu -i 'path/to/private/key/privateKey.cer' -L 3307:aws.port:3306 aws.port -N -v -v
```

**second:** connect to mysql on port 3307

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p
```

**problem:**
it fails with the following error on my host machine:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '178.135.138.61' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

and the log on AWS outputs this:

```
debug1: Connection to port 3307 forwarding to 54.193.1.19 port 3306 requested.
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3307 for 54.193.1.19 port 3306, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 64938, nchannels 3
```

**notes:**

- I made sure that the security group of the aws server i'm connecting to allows `ssh` connections on port 22
- I made sure that `/etc/hosts.deny` on AWS doesn't have localhost or 127.0.0.1 listed.

ideas?

Comment: Your mysql config doesn't allow tcp connections from 178.135.138.61. Fix that.

Comment: @JennyD so do I fix that by putting that ip address into /etc/hosts.allow? I thought I had universal ssh access into my aws.. this is what my security group [looks like](http://postimg.org/image/pgba3vrfd/)

Comment: @JennyD i edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and updated `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`.. but still no luck.. ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '178.135.138.61' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

is coming from MySQL. To allow remote access for user root then you need to specifically allow this for the particular database, on the mysql server

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> grant all privileges on somedatabase.* to 'root'@'178.135.138.61' identified by 'somepassword';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

That will allow the username root to connect to mysql from 178.135.138.61 with all privileges on somedatabase.

You should probably read through the [MySQL Security documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/security.html) in particular the [Access Control](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/privilege-system.html) and [User Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/user-account-management.html) chapters.

Comment: is the `identified by 'somepassword'` part necessary? and if so.. how would i full command to connect to that database look like? i'm getting confused between all the passwords

Comment: @abbood: educate yourself by reading the documentation.

Comment: @lain can't argue with you about that.. i'll def check it out (btw it worked! thanks!)

Comment: @lain is there an omission above, or is this a behavior I'm unfamiliar with? Isn't this implicitly creating a user '178.135.138.61'@'%' rather than 'root'@'178.135.138.61' as written?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: You're right - fixed thanks.